# Line Chart Using MPChartAandroid

Tags: java, android, kotlin, charts, android-native-library

**How to display chart like below ?**

- Only display XAxis lable
- XAxis lable is in string value with multiline
- show value only on first and last plotted value

Please see the screen shot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOEwn.png)

Please help me if anyone have idea about this. Thanks a lot.

I am using MPChart android library and I have tried so many ways which found on stack overflow but could not able to achieve this.

So Please help me if you have any idea about this.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shared your code it is difficult to provide a complete solution. But for your first question:

```
getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```

these two methods disable the vertical axis.
For your 2nd and 3rd questions you should use:

```
chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter();
```

You can find a complete and comprehansive documentation to MPAndroidChart [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

Especifically for line chart this is an example. [Here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartActivity1.java)